# Can we create two bean id for the same bean

Tags: spring

I am trying to make two bean id for a bean.
I am getting NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException.
What could be possible solution to this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Bean id should be unique. If you want to create 2 beans of the same class, provide them different ids/names and then use `@Qualifier` to autowire exact bean.

Answer (score 1):

Create bean manually and give them a name:

```
public class BeanClass {
}

@Configuration
public class ConfigurationClass {

    @Bean(name = "instance1")
    public BeanClass getBeanClass1() {
       return new BeanClass();
    }

    @Bean(name = "instance2")
    public BeanClass getBeanClass2() {
       return new BeanClass();
    }
}
```

Now autowire your bean with `@Qualifier`:

```
@Service
public class YourService {
     @Autowire
     @Qualifier("instance1")
     public BeanClass bean;
}
```

If you want to give a bean as a default bean if not specified (then no need to use `@Qualifier`, then add `@Primary` to your desired bean.

```
@Primary // This tell spring to pick this bean if no `@Qualifier` is presented
@Bean(name = "instance2")
public BeanClass getBeanClass2() {
   return new BeanClass();
}
```

Comment: In my case I have XML where in I am giving two different id to the same bean as I need to have properties different for both.

Comment: Do the samething, give the bean different ID and wire them with assigned ID